# Svg icon fonts for mobile design

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

Should I use svg icons for responsive mobile design ? because of retina display. I read that it is good idea for small icons like header or title etc..

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking exclusively about iOS - you mention retina? I do not know about this platform but SVG is not supported by default on Android. Instead you create a different sets of icons with different sizes.

[I recommend this reading](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Comment: thanks, Can you tell me what is the right icon sizes I should use for retina display

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a good read on the matter.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-arent-you-using-svg/

Bassically, it depends on what you want with your implementation. If you only want to use it on Safari on iOS? go ahead. Fast and fluid. however, if you want users to be able to use other platforms like Android, different browsers on iOS or even Windows Phone, this is not the best option.

Comment: thanks for your answers, 

I mean android,IOS,windows. I realize that there are mobile templates that used svg fonts. 
Can i use svg fonts With modernizr or etc.. for all mobile browsers ?

Comment: I have no idea about using SVG fonts. I normally just use the fonts available on the phones.